# I have my RSA key now what. (onion domain)

Tags: domains

I am using Freedom Hosting to run a hidden service. Its nothing big, just want to work on a small little website me and my friends will use.

I followed a guide on how to generate a key using scallion. I have my keys and ready to start. So I went to custom domain and it asked for the domain and a private key. I the domain and the RSA key and hit sign up but got an error saying "Invalid private key" so I am assuming that it indeed isnt asking for a RSA key.
[image: The Error]